# Catch Error Reading File From Disk - You Don't Have Permissions

Tags: swift, xcode, permissions, openurl

I am using the following code in the AppDel. This is triggered when a user taps on a gpx file or uses the share option to share the file with my app. At this point it is the user that specified that they are allowing my app to access the file so I'm a little confused a to why this is still being denied. Any advice much appreciated.

```
func application(_ app: UIApplication, open url: URL, options: [UIApplication.OpenURLOptionsKey : Any]) -> Bool {
    
    if let dir = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first {
        let fileURL = dir.appendingPathComponent(url.lastPathComponent)
        if FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath: fileURL.path) {
            print("File already exists")
        }
        else {
            do {
                try FileManager.default.copyItem(at: url, to: fileURL)
                print("Did write file to disk")
            }
             catch {
                 DispatchQueue.main.async(){
                         print("Catch error writing file to disk: \(error)")
                 }
             }
        }
    }
    return true
}
```

The error prints to the console as follows:

> Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=257 "The file
> “Beech_Hill_Long_Route.gpx” couldn’t be opened because you don’t have
> permission to view it."
> UserInfo={NSFilePath=/private/var/mobile/Library/Mobile
> Documents/com~apple~CloudDocs/Desktop/Beech_Hill_Long_Route.gpx,
> NSUnderlyingError=0x282c19a70 {Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=1
> "Operation not permitted"}}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm less knowledgeable about exactly how this works on iOS, but I do have some knowledge about how it works for macOS, and the two should be similar.  For macOS sandboxed apps the user has to select the file outside of the sandbox specifically via `NSOpenPanel` or `NSSavePanel`.  The equivalent on iOS would be `UIDocumentPickerViewController`, but I assume an explicit share would work too. Based on that, here's how I would think about it and what I would try, if I were faced with your problem:

You've got two `URL`s involved in your call to `FileManager.default.copy()`.  It's not clear which one is producing the error, so I'll consider both.

First let's look at `fileURL`.  You're constructing it to put a file in the user's `Documents` directory. On macOS at least, that directory is *not* in the app's sandbox, which means asking the user via `NSSavePanel` (which also means they might decide to put it somewhere else).  You might have to do the `UIKit` equivalent, or just make sure you're picking a location that is in your sandbox.

To test that, instead of doing the copy, try writing to `fileURL` to isolate just that one. For example:

```swift
do { try "TestString".data(using: .utf8)?.write(url: fileURL) }
catch { print("Write failed: \(error.localizedDescription)") }
```

If that fails, then your problem is with `fileURL`, in which case you may need to use `UIDocumentPickerViewController` to save it, or pick a location that's definitely in the app's sandbox.

If the test succeeds, the problem must be with the incoming `URL`.

I'm going to assume that `url` is already security scoped, because I'm not sure how sharing would even work otherwise.  What I think is most likely happening behind the scenes is that when the user shares a `URL` with your app, iOS creates a security-scoped bookmark from the `URL` and sends the bookmark rather than the `URL` to your app.  Then on your app's end, that bookmark is used to reconstitute the `URL` before passing it on to your app's delegate.  If I'm right about that you'll need to open and close a security scope to use it:

```swift
url.startAccessingSecurityScopedResource()

// access your file here

url.stopAccessingSecurityScopedResource()
```

Note that `stopAccessingSecurityScopeResource()` has to be called on the main thread, so if you're code is happening asynchronously you'll need to schedule it to run there:

```swift
url.startAccessingSecurityScopedResource()

// access your file here

DispatchQueue.main.async { url.stopAccessingSecurityScopedResource() }
```

If you need to save the `URL` itself to use in a future run of your program... you can't.  Well, you can, but it won't be valid, so you'll be right back to permissions errors.  Instead you have to save a bookmark, and then in that future run, reconstruct the `URL` from the bookmark.

```swift
let bookmark = try url.bookmarkData(
    options: .withSecurityScope, 
    includingResourceValuesForKeys: nil, 
    relativeTo: nil
)
```

`bookmark` is an instance of `Data`, so you can write that to `UserDefaults` or wherever you might want to save it.  To get a `URL` back from it later:

```swift
var isStale = false
let url = try URL(
    resolvingBookmarkData: bookmark, 
    options: .withSecurityScope, 
    relativeTo: nil, 
    bookmarkDataIsStale: &isStale
)

if isStale 
{
    let newBookmark = try url.bookmarkData(
        options: .withSecurityScope, 
        includingResourceValuesForKeys: nil, 
        relativeTo: nil
    )
    // Save the new bookmark
}
```

*Note that if `isStale` is `true` after the initializer returns, then you need to remake and resave the bookmark.*

It's a shame that we have to go through this much trouble, but we live in a world where some people insist on doing bad things to other people's devices and data, so it's what we have to deal with the protect users from malicious data breaches.

Comment: Chip, this is such am in depth answer. I haven't yet tried any of the above suggestions but wanted to say thanks so much for taking the time to explain in detail, I really appreciate it. I'll post back my results ;-)

Comment: Okay so the results are in! You were absolutely spot on chip, it was the startAccessingSecurityScopedResource() which resolve the issue. Thank you so much, I was tearing my hair out for hours trying to resolve this issue. My blood pressure has finally returned to normal!

Comment: Awesome!  I'm glad that my answer was able to help despite having to make assumptions about the similarity with macOS.